# How to remove a middle commit without removing the changes introduced by it?

Tags: git

I have a commit history that looks like this:

`A - B - C`

Now I want the files to remain as they are, but I find that commit `B` is unnecessary.

So I want the history to become:

`A - C`

**keeping** the changes introduced by `B`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### interactive rebase and fixup/squash

An easy way to do so is to do an interactive rebase, and squash two commits together:

```
$ git rebase -i A
```

This will show an editor with a screen like so:

```
pick A commit message
pick B commit message
pick C commit message

# Rebase A..C onto A
```

Simple read the options available, modify the file in your editor, and e.g.:

#### To merge B into A

```
pick A commit message
squash B commit message
pick C commit message
```

#### To merge C into B

```
pick A commit message
pick B commit message
squash C commit message
```

Using squash allows you to then modify the commit message to your liking (for example to use the commit message of C with the resultant commit), if the commit message is not important you can instead use `fixup`.

Answer (score 2):

You can squash commits B and C. Run `git rebase -i sha1_of_A`. It will open a text editor with a list of commits. Put `fixup` on the line of the C commit, save, and exit.

What will happen:

At the beginning you have:

```
A -B - C
       L HEAD
```

After merging the commits you will have:

```
A - B - C
  \ C'
    L HEAD
```

Where C and C' will have the same files.

It means that:

- You will have the commits you want
- Your commits `B` and `C` aren't actually lost, so you can get back to it if you have some remorses
- When you play with interactive rebase, it's easy to add a safety net: tag the commit from where you start, so you'll be able to easily get back to it if things get complicated